# Azure specific reading files from local on spark

Tags: java, azure, hadoop, apache-spark

I am struggling with Azure `wasb` on spark

I am reading loading a `.json.gz` file from disk and loading it into `hdfs`. I have used the following code extensively on other systems.

`val file_a_raw = sqlContext.read.json('/home/users/repo_test/file_a.json.gz')`

However, on Azure, this returns:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: Filewasb://server-2017-03-07t08-13-41-314z@server.blob.core.windows.net/home/users/repo_test/file_a.json.gz does not exist.`

I have checked this location and the file is there and correct.

I think there should be a `:` between `.net` and then file `path`, but I get a java error trying to manually add that in.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme name at index 0:`

I've also tried:

`Filewasb:///home/users/repo_test/file_a.json.gz`

But that returns:

`java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: Filewasb`

This code works fine on non Azure spark

Answer (score 1):

For Azure, you'll need to configure Spark with the proper credentials. Databricks has documentation on this: https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/faq/azure-blob-storage.html

Comment: Thanks! So, it isn't possible to read from local disk? You have to read from azure blob storage? Or is the local disk azure blob storage....

Comment: It would be difficult to read from local disk if the instances are seen as ephemeral. You would first need to copy the files to local disk, but if you have multiple nodes it would be difficult since the files need to be replicated across all nodes.